# jenkinsfile setting environment variable with substring extraction

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Having trouble attempting to set a environment variable that uses substring extraction of another environment variable.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {           
        NODE_BASE_NAME = "ui-node-${GIT_COMMIT:0:6}"
    }
    stages {
        stage ("test") {
            steps {
                echo "${NODE_BASE_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results in

```
WorkflowScript: 4: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 4, column 49.
   NAME = "ui-node-${GIT_COMMIT:0:6}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intrinsic method for doing a substring in Groovy is `String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`. Therefore, the correct syntax for interpolating your string assigned to `NODE_BASE_NAME` with a `GIT_COMMIT` substring is:

```
environment {           
  NODE_BASE_NAME = "ui-node-${GIT_COMMIT.substring(0, 6)}"
}
```